# Headers found for OS X but not for iOS

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

I have created a `cocos2d-x` project as shown [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_create_a_multi-platform_project_in_one_command_line).

In my code I include a Header like this:

```
#include <chaiscript/chaiscript.hpp>
```

When I set the scheme in Xcode to `MyProject Mac > MyMac` it compiles and runs.

But when I try to compile for iOS with `MyProject iOS > iPad 2`

Xcode complains: `'chaiscript/chaiscript.hpp' file not found`

I have compared the Header search paths in the project settings but I cant see any differences!

Comment: Maybe one or both of
`#if defined(__OSX__) ...`
`#if defined(TARGET_OS_IPHONE)...`
somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly a fix, but it works:

As I only depend on Header-Only libraries I copied them directly into the source directory instead of using the ones in `/usr/local/include`